# Find a cell and change its value in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks for taking the time to read my question, I am not a programmer and I hope I can get some help here.

I would like to find a cell in a range and change it's value.

For example, range A1:A20, If "Sales" is in there (like using Vlookup or something) - then change it's value to "Sales Q1" or whatever else I specify.

I appreciate everyone's help and time...

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You could use `find and replace` in excel.

Answer (score 1):

A little old but i've added a little to it to make it so it finds values that are like the string. So for example if I'm looking for Sales1 or sales222 then I'd use this with a wildcard.

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In Sheets

    For i = 1 To 20
    If LCase(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Like "sales*" Then  'ensure the search value is lowercase
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = "Sales Q1"
    End If
    Next
    Next ws
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub replace_sales()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

For i = 1 To 20
If ws.Cells(i, 1) = "Sales" Then
ws.Cells(i, 1) = "Sales Q1"
End If

Next

Next ws

End Sub
```

Couldn't you simply use Ctrl + H.
Btw this code will now replace "Sales" to "Sales Q1" in every sheet of the active workbook -code will look for sales in Rows 1-20 and column 1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply... can you please explain how the code knows where to look? what the 1 To 20 stands for and for which column? thanks a lot ...... reason I don't want to use Ctrl + h is that there are like 100 files I need to do it for and multiple rows for each file...

Comment: Also, I would really appreciate it if you can please update the code to include the worksheet as well... so that I can use the same code for different worksheets .... thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code from the previous answer:

```vb
Sub AnyNameYouLike()
    For i = 1 To 20
        If SheetName.Cells(i, 1) Like "*Sales*" Then
            SheetName.Cells(i, 1) = "Sales Q1"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The call to refer to a cell is: `SheetName.Cells(rowNumber, columnNumber)`. This is, column A becomes column 1, column C is column 3 and so on.

`SheetName` IS NOT the sheet name you see in Excel's tabs. Is the name you see in the VBEditor on the left. The name of the sheet you see in Excel is stated between parentheses.

The `for` instruction executes the lines between the `For` instruction and the `Next` instruction as many times as you instruct it (in this case 20 times) replacing the `i` with a different number every time (first time with 1, second time with 2, last time with 20).

The `Like` instruction allows you to do matches that you wouldn't do with `=`. The `*` means anything, so if you are using `"*Sales*"` means you want to match any cell that contains 0 or some characters, then `Sales` and then 0 or more characters. You could use `"Sales*"` to match a cell starting with `Sales`, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Just wondering, why are you using 20 (the 1 to 20) to execute 20 times?

Comment: If you write correlative numbers, each in a line, from 1 to 20, you will end up using 20 lines. That's the same, if i want something executed 20 times I count from 1 to 20 (although you may also see counting from 0 to 19, especially in other languages like Java or C).